# Getting granted access to a handle

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, systems-programming

A client creates or opens a file, I'm injecting into the client and getting a handle of the file.
From the handle can I get "desired access" the client provided to "CreateFile" function when calling CreateFile or OpenFile functions?

I want to open another file with exactly same access?

I tried [NtQueryObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryobject) but could not find a class which returns handle access values

Comment: *ObjectBasicInformation* - look in `PUBLIC_OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION.GrantedAccess`

Comment: I check this but the value of .GrantedAccess is different than what we see in Process Explorer or Process Hacker

Comment: and so what ? what value view you and what Process Explorer ? faster of all you make mistake somewhere. really *PUBLIC_OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION.GrantedAccess* containing correct infformation always